# How to render part of a PDF file as an image using PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, render, pdfbox

PDFBox offer functions to render a entire page, but no way to render only a specific rectangle of the page.

This code is working for me. But as mentioned above it **renders the whole page** and I need a method to render a little area of the pdf file:

```
    File file = new File("package.pdf"); 
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
    PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
    BufferedImage image = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, 400);
    ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("C:/package1.png"));
    document.close();
```

I would be very happy about a solution, since I have not found a solution for hours

Comment: Have you tried restricting the page to the rectangle in question by setting its crop box to it?

Comment: Or you could render to a graphics device and set a clipping path before calling render.

Comment: Why is this question tagged as an iText question?

Comment: @mkl thank you man crop box was the keyword i needed

Answer (score 7):

I have found a soulution by myself. CropBox was the deciding keyword i did not know about.

```
    File file = new File("package.pdf"); 
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
    PDPage page = document.getPage(0);
    page.setCropBox(new PDRectangle(133f, 150f, 100f, 100f)); // Here you draw a rectangle around the area you want to specify
    PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
    BufferedImage image = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, 400);
    ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("C:/fatihabi.png"));
    document.close();
```